# How to return values from two columns?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with 4 columns. When I look for the min or max from a column I also want the corresponding column from the first column returned as well. Is this possible in R?

Here is the layout of my table:

```
Beach,Date,E_Coli,Enterococci
Balbriggan,26/05/2015,41,13
Donabate,26/05/2015,288,11
Howth - Claremont,26/05/2015,961,280
Loughshinny,26/05/2015,10,3
```

I can get the min and max values for the other columns no problem. Is it possible to pull in the value from the `Beach` column as well?

Comment: you can use `which.max` or `which.min` to get the index for subsetting the rows or another option is `==` i.e. `subset(df1, E_Coli==min(E_Coli))`

Comment: Please edit your question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @akrun's comment:

```
# read in file
df <- read.csv(<filePath>, as.is=T)

# extract row with minimum E_Coli:
min.E_ColiRowq <- df[which.min(df$E_Coli),]

# extract beach name and value of minimum E_Coli:
min.E_ColiRowq <- df[which.min(df$E_Coli), c("Beach", "E_Coli")]
```

The blank spot after the comma in `[...,]` says return all column values. The `c(...)` in `[..., c(...)]` says take selected column values. You use `which.max` for the other operations.

Comment: @Imo. R accepts that code but doesn't return anything when i run it? Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: No. you should now have an object named min.E_ColiRowq. You can see its contents by printing this name in the console and hitting enter. Also, you can see all of the objects in your session by typing `ls()`.